# Why does vim/neovim show the zero width space as <200b>?

Tags: unicode

When I copy a [zero width space](https://symbl.cc/en/200B/) into vim, it is displayed as `<200b>`, instead of it being invisible:

[image: screenshot of the zero width space]

I've tried this in multiple terminal emulators and in both vim and neovim, and the character is always shown this way. Why is this? Is it possible to make vim render it as an actual invisible character?

Edit: Adding information requested in the comments to add images.

> What is the result if you do in insert mode Ctrl-v U000200B1?

[image: Result of oding in insert mode Ctrl-v U000200B1]

> When you go to the character inserted what is the result of the ga command?

For the zero-width space I get `<<200b>> 8203, Hex 200b, Octal 20013`, when inserting `U000200B1` i get the following:

[image: result of the ga command over U000200B1]

Comment: What is the result if you do in insert mode Ctrl-v `U000200B1`? When you go to the character inserted what is the result of the `ga` command?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt I just edited the main post to add the answers to your questions.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt in UTF-8, that's E2 80 8B, so actually C-v `U00e2808b`, which is invisible

Comment: I think the copy from that side is giving you a UTF-16 encoding, since the Unicode codepoint (200b) is encoded in UTF-16 as the same sequence.

Comment: Actually, I take all that back: yank and pasting the `<200b>` character into `xxd` gives the UTF-8 bytes; my system sees any yank starting with the C-v `U00e2808b` character as an empty string, probably because it's an invalid UTF-8 sequence or something. Directly writing the buffer containing that character into `xxd` gives a byte sequence that is probably the UTF-8 encoding of such a bizarre code point. So it seems Vim's `u` and `U` input methods after C-v are using Unicode code points and not their encoding.

Comment: I have been wrong I mean <Ctrl-v>`U0000200b` which indeed is displayed as <200b>

Comment: Or more simply <Ctrl v>u200b. It seems to me that Vim can't display it and choose to show the Unicode code.